# Permission denied when running npm install for meteor on passenger deployment

Tags: meteor, passenger

In [deployment guide](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/digital_ocean/nginx/oss/xenial/deploy_app.html#install-mongodb) `npm install --production` is recommended to run with an user created for that app. It does work for me with root user however if I do exactly as in guide (`sudo -u myappuser -H bash -l`) I get this such error:

```
vdling@513421:/var/www/vdling-admin/bundle/programs/server$ npm install --production
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install /var/www/vdling-admin/bundle/programs/server
> node npm-rebuild.js


> v8-profiler@5.6.5 preinstall /var/www/vdling-admin/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/meteorhacks_kadira-binary-deps/node_modules/v8-profiler
> node -e 'process.exit(0)'


> v8-profiler@5.6.5 install /var/www/vdling-admin/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/meteorhacks_kadira-binary-deps/node_modules/v8-profiler
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied

npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-042stab116.2
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "rebuild" "--no-bin-links" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! v8-profiler@5.6.5 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
```

Seems like some kind of permissions problem but I am not sure where I should change permissions in order for it to work. Also is it not safe to run this command as root?

Comment: can you show an `ls -l` in `bundle/programs/server`?

Comment: Owner is my app's user (I did exactly as in deploy guide which changed owner for everything in bundle)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permission of all directory and file using chown command.
You need to run the command using root user.

```
sudo -R chown myappuser:myappuser *
```